# type safety warning how to avoid for generic assignments

Tags: java, casting, type-safety

I'm using the following code and I have type safety warning for the following lines,

```
Type safety: Unchecked cast from Root<capture#5-of ?> to Root<T>
Type safety: Unchecked cast from CriteriaQuery<capture#4-of ?> to CriteriaQuery<T>
```

there is a way to avoid it without adding suppress?

```
CriteriaQuery<T> criteriaQuery = (CriteriaQuery<T>) criteriaBuilder.createQuery(classReferance);

 Root<T> rootObj = (Root<T>) criteriaQuery.from(classReferance);
```

Comment: Normally there is. First thing to do: Post the defintion of the `createQuery()`-method.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a `classReference` to `createQuery`. The type of `classReference` must be `Class<T>` for the compiler to acknowledge that you are using the same `T` for both the passed-in class and for `CriteriaQuery<T>` criteriaQuery.

You may have a `Class<?>` instead, which prevents type inference.